# Conditional in find and replace php function

Tags: php, find, preg-replace

I have this function which searches for strings like this:

```
<unique>342342342</unique>
<unique>5345345345345435345</unique>
<unique>4444</unique>
```

function:

```
$pattern = '/<unique>(.*?)<\/unique>/';
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern,function($match){
    $value = intval(trim($match[1])/200);
    return '<unique>'.$value.'</unique>';
},$xml);
```

and change the number to its half (n/2). So far so good.

But I need to add a conditional to check if the number has more than 10 digits, if true then makes the change, if not, doesn't.

I tried this, but nope...all instances de '4444' get removed

```
$pattern = '/<unique>(.*?)<\/unique>/';
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern,function($match){

        $valueunique = trim($match[1]);
        if(strlen($valueunique) >= 11){
            $value = intval($valueunique/200);
            return '<unique>'.$value.'</unique>';
            }
},$xml);
```

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. What is your problem?

Comment: @Toto all instances de '<unique>4444</unique>' get removed.

Comment: OK, I see, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the return outside the if block:

```
$xml = '<unique>342342342</unique>
<unique>5345345345345435345</unique>
<unique>4444</unique>';

$pattern = '/<unique>(.*?)<\/unique>/';
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern,function($match){
        $value = trim($match[1]);
        if(strlen($value) >= 11){
            $value = intval($value/200);
        }
        return '<unique>'.$value.'</unique>';
},$xml);

echo "response = $response\n";
```

**Output:**

```
response = <unique>342342342</unique>
<unique>26726726726727180</unique>
<unique>4444</unique>
```